# Json schema object property must be the key of an object

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm currently writing a json schema and I was wondering if someone knows an answer to my problem. Can I ensure that an object's value equals the key of an object somewhere in the JSON. Given the following JSON:

```
{
    "defaultConfig" : "config1",
    "configs" : {
        "config0" : {...},
        "config1" : {...},
        "config2" : {...}
    }
}
```

Can I validate that the content of "defaultConfig" must be one of the keys of the properties of "configs" (e.g. "config0", "config1", "config2")? I can't use enums in this case, as the config names are not known beforehand?

Edit: Here's the schema I have so far:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties" : {
        "defaultConfig" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "configs" : {
            "type" : "object", 
            "patternProperties": {
                "." : {"type" : "object"}
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I think you can't since json schema is used to validate a json, not the schema itself.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing in JSON Schema that allows a keyword to reference a different part of the data instance in that way.

However, the latest version of the specification allows extensions via the $vocabulary keyword, so if you are so inclined, you could write your own keyword that did what you needed.